# Keep some part of a file and process some others by a vbs script file from a batch file

Tags: batch-file, vbscript

I need to keep some part of a file and deal with those items whom I pull from this file. I call a VBScript file from a batch to process those items I want to transform. My goal is to have all of them (items which are transformed by the VBScript process and those which are not concerned by this process) into the same file.

Batch file:

```
 @echo off
 cscript run.vbs findstr /r "^I.=" "%~f1"
```

`run.vbs`:

```
 set objF=createobject("scripting.filesystemobject")
 x=objF.opentextfile(wscript.arguments(0),1).readall
```

Every time that I run batch, it occurs an execution error in my VBScript at the line   `x=objF.opentextfile(wscript.arguments(0),1).readall`. I understand this error because the parameter given at `run.vbs` from batch is not a file.

Answer (score 1):

Try storing the value in a variable before passing it to vbs script may be you can add few checks for exception in the batch script. Can you post some examples.

Comment: Please how to store findstr /r "^I.=" "%~f1" into a variable with batch. I try set P=findstr /r "^I.=" "%~f1", echo p in batch, dim : var=Wscript.Arguments.Named("x") in run.vbs. But cscript run.vbs /x: p>test.txt is giving a text file empty more so echo p shows p and not its content. Thanks

Comment: Let's me say that if i put aside the expression findstr /r "^I.=" "%~f1">result.txt, it works fine. But when keeping that into a variable for vbs script file, it seems that there is an issue since variable is empty (through echo variable name).thanks

Answer (score -1):

If you want to process the output of a batch command in VBScript, you have to do something like this:

```
@echo off

for /f %%a in ('findstr /r "^I.=" "%~f1"') do (
  cscript run.vbs "%~fa"
)
```

It might be easier to do this entirely in VBScript, though:

```
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

Set re = New RegExp
re.Pattern = "^I.=(.*)"

Set f = fso.OpenTextFile(WScript.Arguments.Unnamed(0))

Do Until f.AtEndOfStream
  Set m = re.Execute(f.ReadLine)
  If m.Count > 0 Then
    text = fso.OpenTextFile(Trim(m(0).SubMatches(0))).ReadAll
    'do stuff with text
  End If
Loop

f.Close
```